# Scroll animation

Tags: wpf, animation

How can I animate the the scrolling for ListBox? I know I can use scrollIntoView but how can I animate it? I want to press the arrow keys to move from one listBoxItem to another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a rough implementation based on the same approach as the following link
http://aniscrollviewer.codeplex.com/

The `VerticalOffset` property is read-only so instead you can use an attached property `VerticalOffset` on the `ScrollViewer` which in turn does `ScrollToVerticalOffset`. This attached property can be animated.

You can also create an extension method for `ItemsControl` called `AnimateScrollIntoView`.

Call it like this

```
listBox.AnimateScrollIntoView(yourItem);
```

*ScrollViewerBehavior*

```
public class ScrollViewerBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset",
                                            typeof(double),
                                            typeof(ScrollViewerBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnVerticalOffsetChanged));

    public static void SetVerticalOffset(FrameworkElement target, double value)
    {
        target.SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
    }
    public static double GetVerticalOffset(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        return (double)target.GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
    }
    private static void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = target as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

*ItemsControlExtensions*

```
public static class ItemsControlExtensions
{
    public static void AnimateScrollIntoView(this ItemsControl itemsControl, object item)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(itemsControl);

        UIElement container = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as UIElement;
        int index = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
        double toValue = scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight * ((double)index / itemsControl.Items.Count);
        Point relativePoint = container.TranslatePoint(new Point(0.0, 0.0), Window.GetWindow(container));

        DoubleAnimation verticalAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        verticalAnimation.From = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        verticalAnimation.To = toValue;
        verticalAnimation.DecelerationRatio = .2;
        verticalAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(verticalAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(verticalAnimation, scrollViewer);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(verticalAnimation, new PropertyPath(ScrollViewerBehavior.VerticalOffsetProperty));
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

And since you also need to get a hold of the `ScrollViewer` you'll need this

```
public static class VisualTreeHelpers
{
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);

        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the animation.to value if I want to scroll horizontally?

Comment: There might be an error in the code:

`scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight * ((double)index / itemsControl.Items.Count); `

should be

`scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight * ((double)index / (itemsControl.Items.Count -1)); `

for example, if the list contains 12 elements and I want to scroll to the last one (index 11), the result has to become 

`scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight * 1`

also, beware of division by zero :)

Comment: @sim1: Haven't looked at this one for a long time so I'm sure you're right. Thanks for the update :)

Comment: +1, awesome. One question though, what's the `translatePoint` variable in `AnimateScrollIntoView` for? It's currently unused...

Comment: @RobFonseca-Ensor: This was a while ago but I guess it was something I used during debugging and forgot to delete :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://therobotgeek.net/articles/WPF_Scrolling_Content.aspx), it explains how animate scrolling and add touch gestures. Download the source at the bottom of the page and look at WpfScrollContent solution. I would extend the WPF ListBox and add the scroll animation to it that way you can reuse the control.

Comment: @evanb which is exactly why answers that contain nothing but links are discouraged.