# Animate DataGrid to Auto Scroll

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid, .net-4.5

I have a DataGrid that has 2 rows of data, but I only have space to display 1 row at a time. I would like to implement some sort of animation to automatically scroll to the row 2, pause and then scroll back to row 1. I tried to use translate transform with double animation, but that only moves the row 1 back and forth.

Also, I don't have a header for this DataGrid, so I don't have to worry about making the header visible while scrolling.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DataGrid.ScrollIntoView`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324321.aspx

with custom animation as explained here ... [Scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153302/scroll-animation)